# Aggregate Sliding Window for hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, sliding-window

I have a hive table which is in sorted order based on a numeric value say count.

```
fruit   count
------  -------
apple   10
orange  8
banana  5
melon   3
pears   1
```

The total count is 27. I need it divided into three segments. So first 1/3 of count i.e. 1 to 9 is one, 10 to 18 is second and 19 to 27 is third.
I guess I need to do some sought of sliding window.

```
fruit   count    zone
------  ------- --------
apple   10      one
orange  8       two
banana  5       three
melon   3       three
pears   1       three
```

Any idea how to approach this

Comment: What would the results be if the first count were 50?  (That is, more than 2/3s of the total value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL way:

```
select *,
(
sum(count)  over (partition by 1 order by count desc) /*<---this line for return running totals*/
/(sum(count) over (partition by 1) /3) /*<-- divided total count into 3 group. In your case this is 9 for each zone value.*/
) /*<--using running totals divided by zone value*/
+ /*<-- 11 / 9 = 1 ... 2  You must plus 1 with quotient to let 11 in the right zone.Thus,I use this + operator  */
(
case when 
(
sum(count)  over (partition by 1 order by count desc)
%(sum(count) over (partition by 1) /3) /*<--calculate remainder */
) >1 then 1 else 0 end /*<--if remainder>1 then the zone must +1*/
)  as zone
from yourtable
```

Comment: what does the + operator stand for?

Comment: @JohnConstantine      18 and 23 divided by 9 is 2. 23 belong zone 3.   Because in your example 10 belong zone 1,I use + operator for add 1 when remainder >1.  If you want 10 belong zone 2,you add 1 when remainder >0.